# Having trouble with an age check moethod in user model after over-riding devise registration controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to set up an age restriction when a user registers so that if they are too young they cannot register on an app i'm building.

I had to over-ride devise to allow me to pass through other values to the user (like `:birth_date`). However I also want to check the age of the user so that if they are too young, they cannot use the app.

What I have right here, in a rudimentary way it works, but it is not quite what I would like.

```
    <%= f.input :birth_date, required: true, start_year:1999 %>
```

In my user model I created some methods that address the problem, however ultimately my problem is that none of this code is getting hit during the registration process, and that is what I need some help with. If someone could take a look at point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it!

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validate :age_restriction

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :cafes


  def age_restriction
    if (birth_date.to_date + 18.years) < Date.today # assuming dob format is mm/dd/yy
      errors.add :birth_date, 'must be older than 18'
    end
  end
end
```

The controller I used to over-ride devise I called `registration_controller` and it is like so

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: :create
  before_action :configure_account_update_params, only: :update

  protected
  def configure_sign_up_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:birth_date])
  end

  def configure_account_update_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:bith_date])
  end
end
```

My initial controller was my user_controller. Initially I was hoping this would solve my issue, but after some more work realized I needed to over-ride devise (hence the other `registrations_controller`). I'll admit this may be what is causing me my issue, not sure though.

```
class UsersController < ActiveRecord::Base
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @user = current_user.build(user_params)
    @user.save
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:birth_date)
  end
end
```

Comment: Have you considered using validations in your user model ?

Comment: Your User model inherits from `ApplicationRecord`, Is that normal ? Shouldn't it be `ActiveRecord::Base` ?

Comment: I added the `::Base` on it, and wound up with an error when trying to restart my server at ` uninitialized constant ApplicationRecord::Base`

Comment: It’s ActiveRecord::Base not ApplicationRecord::Base. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html

Comment: well, i changed it to `ActiveRecord::Base`. restarted my server. then tried to create a new patient at an age that was too young, and it still allowed the user to register. :(

Comment: Your `UsersController` should inherit from `ApplicationController` not `ActiveRecord::Base` http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html

Comment: hm......switched that to the correct `ApplicationController` but still no luck. I do want to say thank you though for your willingness to take a look at this with me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155465/discussion-between-cyzanfar-and-kdweber89).

Answer (score 0):

Use validations.

There is a gem which adds some useful date validators:
https://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness/

```
validates_date :date_of_birth, :before => lambda { 18.years.ago },
                               :before_message => "must be at least 18 years old"
```

Comment: I honestly don't think this is a good use of an external library. You can achieve the same functionality with minimal code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use model [validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) to prevent a user instance from being created if the user does not meet the age restriction you have set:

*User.rb*

```
  validate :age_restriction


  def age_restriction
    if (birth_date.to_date + 18.years) < Date.today # assuming dob format is mm/dd/yy
      errors.add :birth_date, 'must be older than 18'
    end
  end
```

Comment: Yeah, so i've tried something similar (and now, i've tried yours). But for some reason, it seems like nothing in the user model is getting hit. The validation is ignored. (I think my code is not using my model, and I don't know why)

Comment: That's very strange... You should have control over your users being created, that's not something that is handled by devise. Could you show us your user model?